# ComboBox blank text with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, listview, combobox, vb.net-2010

I have here the code of my combobox in VB.net which is connected to my SQL Server 2012.

```
Public Sub LoadCBXStocks(Optional QueryForCBXStocks As String = "")
    If QueryForCBXStocks = "" Then
    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM tblProduct ORDER BY Category ASC;")
    Else
    SQL.ExecQuery(QueryForCBXStocks)
    End If

    If SQL.HasException(True) Then 
       Exit Sub

    cbxStocksCategory.Items.Clear()

    For Each r As DataRow In SQL.DBDT.Rows
        cbxStocksCategory.Items.Add(r("Category").ToString)
    Next

    cbxStocksCategory.Items.Add("")
End Sub
```

I'm trying to add a blank text to my combobox and I've successfully done it. Now my problem is when I select the blank text in my combobox, all of my data in my listview goes to blank data BUT when I select the items that is not blank text (as you can see in my for each loop, the `Category` is the column name and under that I have Drinks, Grilled etc.). My `Listview` shows the data which is base also on my query that you can see in if else condition.

What I want is when I select the blank text on my combobox. My Listview will show all the data like when it is first show (I mean without filtered)

If you, reading this cannot get specifically what I want please bear with me and I will try to edit it so you can get my thoughts.

Thank you.

Comment: Debug your own code first. There must be an event that fires in your app when a value in the combobox is selected. So you start with the code that handles that event. 

And your schema is (or will eventually be) a problem. You should a table of allowed categories and a foreign key between that table and products. If you allow users to just randomly type in anything, you will eventually find that you have many logical duplicates that vary only slightly (spelling, abbreviation, mistakes, etc.)

Comment: And do yourself and your organization a big favor and make your code and database match the purpose and GUI. Your routine is named "stocks" but it loads "categories" from "products". This type of deviation makes managing, learning, understanding, and documenting your system difficult.

Comment: -I'd already have my code for the event that fires in my app.. This is just the public sub that contains all of my code for that event in my combobox. 

-Yes I did understand you but this is just a small app from school. And the reason for the "category" that inside the "stocks" is for viewing(I used it by filtering in the listview as you can see in my query).

Comment: Why don't you load the SQL results into a data adapter, then have the combo box point to that?